# How do I find empty cells or cells with &nbsp in td in table and make it editable using js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am working with huge table like I have 5000 tds and I want make all the empty cells or cells with only &nbsp editable using js and jQuery.

Comment: You should read up on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There is no way to give you a good answer given your question.

Comment: what do you mean by 'editable'? What have you tried?

Comment: its just a huge table and i want to make every empty cells or cells with space(&nbsp)  as input field

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Comment: @JasonC Im not sure what the point of the link is?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs You asked "what do you mean by 'editable'?"

Comment: @JasonC ah I see thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this .`trim()` will ignore the `&nbsp;`

```js
$('td').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).text().trim()) {
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', true)
  }
})
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td> </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td></td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td></td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
  <tr><td>one</td><td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><tr>
</table>
```